# How to get only JSON object values from a JSON array in LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

My database query is below.

```
$beneficiary_id = DB::select('select Telephone from item ');
```

This returns a json array looks like this

```
[{"Telephone":"0111222333"},{"Telephone":"0112211223"},{"Telephone":"012345557"},{"Telephone":"0225545455"}]
```

For another database insertion operation I need only the telephone numbers. 
I have used `json_decode()` function, it is working only if we enter the array manually.

How to get only those values to another array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you see when you use `json_decode`?

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. Code I have used.
$tp = json_decode($beneficiary_id);
        return $tp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries) function

> If you would like to retrieve an array containing the values of a single column, you may use the pluck method.

```
$titles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
}
```

Comment: when I use the method, it returns."
Call to a member function pluck() on a non-object"

Comment: How you're using it? Try maybe something like this: `$numbers = DB::table('item')->pluck('Telephone');`

Comment: Yes, It worked.This just returns only the telephone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use $beneficiary_id->column_name to get the value from your object.